# I am using external javascript file in angular 8. It showing an error that function is not defined. But i have defined the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, angular8

In this code, I am trying to use external javascript for toggle password visibility. But it is showing error.

This is my Html code

```
<input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput">
<button (click)="func()">Show Password</button>
```

This is my component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare const myFunction:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angularSecond';
  name:string = 'name';
  allowNewServer = false;  

  constructor()
  {

  }
  func()
  {
    myFunction();
  }
}
```

this is my angular.json file

```
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/jquery.js"
            ]
```

This is my external javascript file

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
      x.type = "text";
    } else {
      x.type = "password";
    }
  }
```

this is the error showing in the webpage

```
AppComponent.html:7 ERROR ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at AppComponent.func (app.component.ts:20)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must export the function from the javascript file.

function declaration:

```
export function myFunction() {
     ...
}
```

Then you need to import it in at the top of the angular component. Instead of

```
declare const myFunction:any;
```

It would be

```
import {myFunction} from 'filepath to file';
```

And you should be good to go to use `myfunction` in your angular project.

Comment: Thank you. The functionality is working perfectly but it is showing error in webpage 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export'